# How to deploy a Java EE project that has web services

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I already have an enterprise Java EE application. I want expose some of the existing EJBs as web services.

I wanted to know how to organize the Java EE project. I mean where does the web services sit in the Java EE EAR file hierarchy and how to invoke the deployed webs services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon exactly how you implement your WebService and also on which Java EE version you are using. Simplest, with JAX-WS your webservice implementation and interface are all packed in the WAR. See [the sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html). Possibly you may implement your service as an EJB and in which case you can simply use the @WebService annotation. In which case you're delivering the EJB jar.

Recommend you work through a few tutorials for the specific App Server you are using.